# jQuery Image Swap - Reset all other images

Tags: jquery

The Swap portion of the code below works just fine but the Reset part is where I'm having trouble. What I want to happen is when you click on one of the images in the list, they all revert back to the _off image and then the one you clicked on switches to _over.

Thanks in advance.

```
 // Reset 
 $('.show').attr('src').replace("_over","_off");

 // Swap                        
 if($(this).attr("class") == "show") {
    this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_over");
 } else {
    this.src = this.src.replace("_over","_off");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do it when binding the image click event handler since the only thing you need to know is which one is the currently clicked 'img' element.

```
$('img').click(function(){ // <-- when img is clicked
     $(this).attr('src','_over'); // <-- change current clicked img            src = _over
     $('img').not(this).attr('src','_off'); // <-- change all other img to     src= _off
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tkp4E/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value returned from `.attr` is not going to change the element. Therefore, what is one of the following:

If there is only one item with the `show` class:

```
$('.show')[0].src.replace("_over","_off");
```

If there is more than one,

```
$('.show').each( function() {
  this.src.replace("_over","_off");
});
```